# It is possible to get a user id from an android when he using a app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I want to get a user id / Google id from a app user without Google sign in. Is it possible to identify a user without authentication?

I want to sync data between devices without a login.

Thank you for any tips like classes or anything else.

Comment: No, that would be a security issue.

Comment: How else would you know it's an actual user? Either use Google sign in or another like email, Apple, Facebook (Meta), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to identify a user without authentication?

No. Identifying a user is basically the literal definition of "authentication". It's like asking if you can get wet without using a liquid.